# How to communicate between addon process and panel page in Jetpack

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

What is the best way to send a variable to a panel? Do people use mustache.js? Right now I am able to load an HTML file but I am not able to communicate with it once i call panel.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate between the panel page and the add-on's module you should use `panel.port` (from the addon module) or `self.port` (from the content script). See [Communicating with Content Scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html#content_script_events) for details.